# elisp - print result not found after eval-buffer

Tags: eval, print

Create a `test.el` file as below:

```
(print "hello world!")
```

Then run `M-x eval-buffer`. No output can be seen even in `*Messages*` buffer. where is the print output for this case?

Answer (score 3):

Nowhere.  See the docstring (`C-h f eval-buffer`):

> (eval-buffer &optional BUFFER PRINTFLAG FILENAME UNIBYTE
>   DO-ALLOW-PRINT)
>
> Execute the accessible portion of current buffer as Lisp code.
>   ...
>
> PRINTFLAG controls printing of output by any output functions in the
>    evaluated code, such as ‘print’, ‘princ’, and ‘prin1’:
>     a value of nil means discard it; anything else is the stream to print to.
>     See Info node ‘(elisp)Output Streams’ for details on streams.
>
> ...
>
> DO-ALLOW-PRINT, if non-nil, specifies that output functions in the
>    evaluated code should work normally even if PRINTFLAG is nil, in
>    which case the output is displayed in the echo area.

Comment: @JeanPiere Thanks, but if I do it as `  (eval-buffer nil (get-buffer-create "test"))`, it works but 1) all function name printed automatically. 2) the print output is duplicated. Maybe I missed some configure!

Comment: @lucky1928 If you do `C-x C-e` (`eval-last-sexp`) with point after the `(print "hello")` you will see the text appears two times in the echo area.  One is the result of evaluation, the other is the string printed by side effect. Try this with `(+ 4 2)` for example.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(message "hello world!")
```

will print `hello world!` to the echo area.  That's the same space that's used by the minibuffer: echo area for output, minibuffer for input.